# iPhone - semi transparent black status bar over the application

Tags: iphone, statusbar

In my iphone application, I want to have my view to be of height 480 pixesl.
And above that, at the top, I want to have semi transparent black status bar over my view so that the back ground image in my view must be slightly visible behind status bar.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this if it works
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
and send your imageView to the back.
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];

Comment: Do I have to set the size of my view to 480 pixels height? I am already setting the status bar style to black translucent in my applicationDidFinishLauching delegate method. And my image view is alreay sent to back in XIB.

Comment: yes u have to set it to 480. and u also need to check its y position. if u r setting y position to 0 and not achieving solution.try setting y to -10. I have not done this but hope u get the solution

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is to set:
1- self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; //in your view controller
2- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent]; //for your status bar.